# What's the difference between わけです。 and はずです。?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> 実験のやり方を変えてみたんです。今度はきっと成功する**はずです**。期待していてください。

vs

> 実験のやり方を変えてみたんです。だから、こんなにいい結果が出た**わけです**。

Can someone explain what the difference between these two sentences above is? Mainly the difference between はず and わけ.

They both mean the same thing to me, the experiment was changed so the output should be a success.

What gives?

Comment: Closely related（わけ）: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/how-to-end-a-sentence-in-%e3%82%8f%e3%81%91/2258#2258

Answer (score 2):

`今度はきっと成功するはずです` means `It should be successful this time`.

今度 means [this time](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BB%8A%E5%BA%A6), きっと is an adverb indicating [certainty](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8), 成功する is a suru verb that means [to succeed](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%88%90%E5%8A%9F) and [はず](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A), a noun, which can appear at the end of a sentence followed by だ or です to mean 'to be supposed to (do)'. It is used when the speaker draws a conclusion from preexisting understandings.

`だから、こんなにいい結果が出たわけです` means `In this way, I got a good outcome`.

だから is a conjunction indicating [consequence](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89), こんなに is an adverb  meaning [in this way](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB), いい is an adjective meaning [good](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%84%E3%81%84), 結果 is a noun meaning [result](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C), 出た is the past form of 出る that, in this case, means [to get](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B). Finally, わけ is a noun that means [reason](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91). This noun can be followed by だ or です at the end of a sentence to mean 'that's why' and it can follow:

- Adjectives and verbs in the dictionary or ta-form.
- Adjectival nouns or nouns + na/no or datta

In this case it follows 出た.

---

As for `実験のやり方を変えてみたんです`, which means `I changed the way I experimented`, you may consult:

- [Saying "try" in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29928/saying-try-in-japanese) ~てみる
- [What is the meaning of ~んです/~のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-etc)

Comment: I wonder if the poster is trying to get at the diffences between:     

実験のやり方を変えてみたんです。今度はきっと成功するはずです。     

And     

実験のやり方を変えてみたんです。今度はきっと成功するわけです。

Comment: I specifically said in my post: Mainly the difference between はず and わけ.  YES I mean the difference between the 2 sentences, thank you.